# how to implement authentication using shared preferences in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android.my requirement is to implement simple authentication logic for login screen by using sharedpreferences in android.
can any one suggest me...?

Answer (score 4):

To save details after registration of user (when user is created)...

```
// Get the app's shared preferences
SharedPreferences login_app_preferences =  context.getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_DETAILS", MODE_PRIVATE);

// Update fields
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login_app_preferences.edit();
editor.putString("email", strEmailOrLoginId);
editor.putString("password", strPassword);
editor.commit(); // Very important
```

To access it any where in application....

```
// Get the app's shared preferences
SharedPreferences login_app_preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_DETAILS", MODE_PRIVATE);

strUserName = login_app_preferences.getString("email", "");
strPassword = login_app_preferences.getString("password", "");
```